# Bare minimum criteria to have name engraved on the Stanley cup

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, stanley-cup

I became curious what the bare minimum requirements are to have one's name engraved on the Stanley cup.

Below is what I found [here](https://www.msgnetworks.com/2017/04/10/10-random-facts-about-the-stanley-cup-trophy/).

> The official rule is that for a player to have their name engraved
> on the Stanley Cup, they must have played at least half the regular
> season (41 games) or one game in the Stanley Cup Finals for the
> Cup-winning team.

When they say "one game in the Stanley cup Finals," does it mean one of the games in the Stanley cup final series?

So, if someone played only one of the conference final series games and only 10 regular season games, that player would not qualify for their name to be etched on to the cup?

Answer (score 3):

Correct. A player must play in the Stanley Cup Finals series or 41 regular season games to automatically qualify for engraving on the Stanley Cup. A team can petition for others to be included, but this is usually reserved for injured players.

As an example, in 2018 Jakub Jerabek was acquired by the Washington Capitals in a near trade deadline deal, played 11 regular season games and the first two games of the first round playoff series. His name is not engraved on the Stanley Cup for the Caps.